# the flag ' ' is not recognized

Tags: bash, arcsight

I need to write a bash script who's first job is to export a package from an arcsight ESM. afterwards it needs to move the exported archives to a connector server but i haven't gotten to that part yet. my issue is this: as per the arcsight ESM manual, the command for exporting the package is the following:

```
arcsight package –action export –package “/All Packages/Personal/Mypackage” –f packagebundle.arb –u username –p password –m managername
```

the command needs to be run from the `arcsight` home directory on the ESM server only, else bash doesn't recognize `arcsight` as a command. i did that, the command seems to run fine as it does manage to log in to ESM, return says it's exporting the package but then i get

> The Flag '' is not recognized

and it stops. it doesn't finish exporting the package as there is no "packagebundle.arb" file in the destination folder after the running the command. so i'd like to ask if anyone has some idea about what this error is and how to fix it. couldn't find much about it until now. ArcSight version is 6.9 and linux version is RHEL 5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are quoting with a curly quote, like this: “, instead of a straight quote, like this: ".

Some text editors change straight quotes to curly because they looks better. This does however break shell executables, because it does not recognize curly quotes.

Here is what your command should look like with straight quotes `arcsight package –action export –package "/All Packages/Personal/Mypackage" –f packagebundle.arb –u username –p password –m managername`

Example: echoing with straight vs curly quotes

Straight quotes:

```
echo "test"
> test
```

Qurly quotes:

```
echo “test“
> “test“
```

As you can see bash does not interpret “ as a quote.

Comment: tried copying straight quotes with shift+insert but i still get curly quotes... do you by any chance know how to type straight quotes in bash? thanks

Comment: @heronpilot This is a problem with your terminal emulator, editor, or other environment, not `bash`.

Comment: alright managed to get it to work by removing the quotes entirely and changing the target file's path. appreciate the effort tho

Comment: @heronpilot If you solved the problem, post an answer to your own question :)